# tf.unsortedSegmentSum does not aggregate all indices?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js

- Tensorflow JS : version 4.16.0
- Backend : webgpu

```js
        // https://js.tensorflow.org/api/4.17.0/#unsortedSegmentSum
        const onesTensor = tf.ones([size * size], 'float32');
        const countTensor = tf.unsortedSegmentSum(onesTensor, indexTensor, size * size);
        console.log("onesTensor shape =", onesTensor.shape, "; dtype =", onesTensor.dtype);
        console.log("indexTensor shape =", indexTensor.shape, "; dtype =", indexTensor.dtype);
        console.log("countTensor shape =", countTensor.shape, "; dtype =", countTensor.dtype);
        console.log("size * size =", size * size);
        const indexBuffer = indexTensor.arraySync();
        console.log("indexBuffer valid element number ="
            , indexBuffer.map((v) => (v >= 0 && v < size * size) ? 1 : 0).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
        );
        const data = countTensor.arraySync();
        console.log("total =", data.reduce((a, b) => a + b));
```

I have the above code using `tf.unsortedSegmentSum` to calculate the sum of the ones based on the indices in `indexTensor`.
Here is output from console.

```
onesTensor shape = [88804] ; dtype = float32
indexTensor shape = [1000000] ; dtype = int32
countTensor shape = [88804] ; dtype = float32
size * size = 88804
indexBuffer valid element number = 1000000
total = 88804
```

As you can see, there are 1000000 indices in `indexBuffer` but there are only 88804 indices aggregated.  Actually those 88804 indices are aggregated correctly, I can see duplicates are counted,  I can see the graph if I draw in heatmap.  But there are 1000000 valid indices and total should be 1000000.

Why are only 88804 indices counted?

Comment: In TensorFlow.js, tf.unsortedSegmentSum operates in a similar fashion to its TensorFlow counterpart, which means it performs a segmented sum of data based on the segments defined by indexTensor. From your output, it seems like there are 88804 unique indices in indexTensor that are being used as segments. This means that despite having 1000000 total indices, only 88804 of them are distinct. The function tf.unsortedSegmentSum is correctly summing the elements within each of these 88804 segments.

Comment: @Sagar, it counts the first 88804 indexes from indexTensor.  And they are not unique.  The first 88804 indexes are counted correctly -- when there are multiple indexes referring to the same location,  it is counted multiple times.  I think it is a bug. raised here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/8174